# Compute directly that the mapping cone of a homotopy equivalence is contractible

Tags: modules, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory, graded-modules

Let's consider the category $Ch_R$ of cochain complexes of modules over a commutative ring $R$. I'm trying to prove that if the chain map $\phi:M\rightarrow N$ is a homotopy equivalence then its mapping cone is contractible, WITHOUT using results from triangulated categories (i.e. by crude computation): by hypothesis i have that there is $\psi:N\rightarrow M$ such that

$$
\psi^k\phi^k-1^k_M=d^{k-1}_M\rho^k+\rho^{k+1}d_M^k \quad and\quad \phi^k\psi^k-1^k_N=d^{k-1}_N\sigma^k+\sigma^{k+1}d_N^k
$$
for some $\rho:M\rightarrow M[-1]$ and $\sigma:N\rightarrow N[-1]$, and i need to find $R:cone\phi\rightarrow cone\phi[-1]$ such that 
$$
1^k_{cone\phi}=\bigg( \matrix{1^k_{M[1]} & 0 \\ 0 & 1^k_N} \bigg)=\bigg(\matrix{-d^k_M & 0 \\ \phi^k & d_N^{k-1}} \bigg)R^k+R^{k+1}\bigg(\matrix{-d_M^{k+1} & 0 \\ \phi^{k+1} & d_N^k} \bigg).
$$
I already worked out that $R^k=\bigg(\matrix{\rho^{k+1} & \psi^k \\ X^k & -\sigma^k}\bigg)$, but i'm stuck with this last equation

$$
\sigma^{k+1}\phi^{k+1}-\phi^k\rho^{k+1}=d^{k-1}_NX^k-X^{k+1}d^{k+1}_M\quad(*)
$$

which is supposed to say that $(\sigma\phi)[1],\phi\rho[1]:M[1]\rightarrow N$ are chain homotopic (or at least they would be if they were chain maps), or that $\phi$ commutes with the chain homotopies if $X$ is a closed morphism of degree -2 (i would like to set $X=0$, but that seems unlikely).

Does this make sense to anyone?

EDIT: If conversely $cone\phi$ is contractible then there is a morphism

$$
R=\bigg(\matrix{\rho[1] & \psi \\ X & -\sigma}\bigg):cone\phi\rightarrow cone\phi[-1]
$$

such that $1_{cone\phi}=d_{cone\phi}[-1]R+R[1]d_{cone\phi}$, and thus $\psi$ is a homotopy inverse of $\phi$ and all the conditions above are satisfied.

Since I'm pretty sure that being a homotopy equivalence and having a contractible cone are equivalent conditions there must be a way to prove that equation (*) always holds (I think it all comes down to showing that the square

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
M & \stackrel{\rho}{\longrightarrow} & M[-1] \\
\downarrow{\phi} & & \downarrow{\phi[-1]} \\
N & \stackrel{\sigma}{\longrightarrow} & N[-1]  
\end{array}
$$

is homotopy commutative, at least for a suitable choice of $\rho$ and $\sigma$).

EDIT2: I think that the following diagram is homotopy commutative, and should solve the problem

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
M & \stackrel{\rho}{\longrightarrow} & M[-1] \\
\downarrow{\phi} & \approx & \downarrow{\phi[-1]} \\
N & \stackrel{\phi[-1]\rho\psi}{\longrightarrow} & N[-1]  \\
\downarrow{1} & \approx & \downarrow{1} \\
N & \stackrel{\sigma}{\longrightarrow} & N[-1]  
\end{array}
$$

But I still would like someone else's opinion about it.

Answer (score 3):

Since I ran into this problem myself and this question is one of the first results via google, it seems helpful to leave an answer here:
The explicit construction is given in the proof of Proposition 1.1 in Ranicki, "The algebraic theory of finiteness obstruction".
The desired chain homotopy is given by
\begin{pmatrix}
k-fhg+kfg & (-1)^{r+1}fhh-kfh \\
(-1)^{r-1}g & h \\
\end{pmatrix}
in Ranickis notation. Ranicki explains his notation right before the Proposition. Roughly, $f=\phi$, $g=\psi$, $h=\rho$ and $k=\sigma$, $r=n$ and the summands of $cone(f)$ are flipped.
The calculation to show that this defines a contraction (which Ranicki omits) works by plugging in the fundamental equations of the chain homotopies ($ch+hc=Id-gf$ and $dk+kd=Id-fg$) at every opportunity.

Comment: I wrote down the details here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1962227 The calculations are not that difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add another answer that seems to occupy some middle ground between the explicit formula in Ranicki's paper and the (for some of us) enigmatic statement "it follows from results about triangulated categories". The following is adapted from Proposition 0.7 (page 7) in Brown's book "Cohomology of Groups". I'll talk about chain complexes instead of cochain complexes, since that's what Brown does.

**Preparatory observation**: For any pair of chain complexes $(A_*,\partial^A)$ and $(B_*,\partial^B)$, there is a chain complex $(\operatorname{Hom}(A_*,B_*),\partial)$ whose degree $n$ part consists of the homomorphisms $\varphi : A_* \to B_*$ of degree $n$ (meaning $\varphi(A_k) \subset B_{k+n}$ for each $k$), with boundary operator given by
$$
\partial\varphi := \partial^B \circ \varphi - (-1)^{|\varphi|} \varphi \circ \partial^A.
$$
In particular, this makes the obvious evaluation map $\operatorname{Hom}(A_*,B_*) \otimes A_* \to B_*$ into a chain map, and as a special case, taking $B_*$ to be trivial in all degrees other than zero gives the usual dualization of $A_*$ that turns homology into cohomology (in which case one would normally put a minus sign in front of the degree and call $\operatorname{Hom}(A_*,B_*)$ a *cochain* complex).  Most importantly for present purposes, the 0-cycles in $\operatorname{Hom}(A_*,B_*)$ are precisely the chain maps from $A_*$ to $B_*$, and two such cycles are homologous if and only if they are chain homotopic.

Next, one needs to do two preparatory exercises, both of which are straightforward. (I'm not just saying that---in fact I quite often criticize authors for trying to impress/intimidate their readers by characterizing things as straightforward in spite of some non-obvious details---but I was able to do these exercises in a state of diminished mental capacity due to illness, so I really do think they are straightforward.)

**Exercise 1**: For any chain complex $C_*$, there is a functor sending each chain complex $A_*$ to the chain complex $\operatorname{Hom}(C_*,A_*)$ and each chain map $f : A_* \to B_*$ to the chain map
$$
\operatorname{Hom}(C_*,f) : \operatorname{Hom}(C_*,A_*) \to \operatorname{Hom}(C_*,B_*) : \varphi \mapsto f \circ \varphi,
$$
and moreover, the chain homotopy class of $\operatorname{Hom}(C_*,f)$ depends only on the chain homotopy class of $f$.

**Exercise 2**: For any chain map $f : A_* \to B_*$ and any third chain complex $C_*$, there is a natural isomorphism between the chain complexes $\operatorname{Hom}(C_*,\operatorname{cone}(f))$ and $\operatorname{cone}(\operatorname{Hom}(C_*,f))$.

With these ingredients in place, we can very quickly prove:

**Theorem**: For any chain homotopy equivalence $f : A_* \to B_*$, the complex $\operatorname{cone}(f)$ is chain contractible.

**Proof**: Abbreviate $C_* := \operatorname{cone}(f)$.  By Exercise 1, $\operatorname{Hom}(C_*,f) : \operatorname{Hom}(C_*,A_*) \to \operatorname{Hom}(C_*,B_*)$ is also a chain homotopy equivalence, and its mapping cone is naturally isomorphic to $\operatorname{Hom}(C_*,C_*)$ according to Exercise 2, so the long exact sequence of the mapping cone implies that $\operatorname{Hom}(C_*,C_*)$ is acyclic.  In particular, $H_0(\operatorname{Hom}(C_*,C_*)) = 0$, which means that every chain map $C_* \to C_*$ is nullhomotopic, including the identity. QED

Incidentally, I found this question because there is a formula equivalent to Ranicki's in Spanier's classic Algebraic Topology book (Theorem IV.2.10 on page 167), and it seemed to me very mysterious: I was hoping to find some deeper ideas that could motivate the origin of such a formula.  The chain contraction in the argument above comes from the exactness of the sequence relating the homologies of $\operatorname{Hom}(C_*,A_*)$, $\operatorname{Hom}(C_*,B_*)$ and $\operatorname{Hom}(C_*,C_*)$, so I'd bet that if you delve into the algebraic details of why that sequence is exact, you will eventually recover that formula.  But I'm going to have to be exceptionally bored before I can motivate myself to do that particular exercise.

Also incidentally, one can use a variation on the same argument to prove the converse: if $\operatorname{cone}(f)$ is chain contractible, one deduces that both of the maps $H_0(\operatorname{Hom}(A_*,A_*)) \to H_0(\operatorname{Hom}(A_*,B_*))$ and $H_0(\operatorname{Hom}(B_*,A_*)) \to H_0(\operatorname{Hom}(B_*,B_*))$ induced by $f$ are bijections, and in light of the interpretation of $H_0$ is chain homotopy classes of chain maps, it is a very short step from there to the conclusion that $f$ is a chain homotopy equivalence. On the other hand, this is the easy direction, so the proof you get by this argument is not shorter than just deriving explicit formulas for a chain homotopy inverse and chain homotopies from a chain contraction of $\operatorname{cone}(f)$.