# Homotopy equivalence gives the mapping cone null homotopic?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an additive category. And let $C(\mathcal{A})$ be the category of the chain complexes. Now let $f:X_* \rightarrow Y_*$ be a chain map in $C(\mathcal{A})$ and $C(f)$ be its mapping cone. As we've already known, there's a proposition:

> If $C(f)$ is contractible, then $f:X_* \rightarrow Y_*$ is a homotopy equivalence.

My question: Is the inverse problem true? To be explicitly, if $f:X_* \rightarrow Y_*$ is a homotopy equivalence, then does $C(f)$ necessarily to be contractible? I guess that this is not true in general for a part of the proof of the proposition doesn't holds conversely. Am I right? If I'm right, is there any counterexample? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The correct terminology is for a chain complex to be contractible rather than null homotopic, which is reserved for describing chain maps. I believe your question has been answered [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/73687).

Comment: @Tyrone Thanks for your advice. I made a mistake. But the OP mentioned “it’s obvious” and I’m bit of confused. I don’t know how to construct $C(f) \simeq 0$ with $X \rightarrow Y$ being a homotopy equivalence. Could you enlighten me?

Comment: So in particular it is actually true that if $f$ is a homotopy equivalence then $C(f)$ is contractible. The link I provide is written in the context of cohomologically graded complexes, but you just need to reverse the grading to get homologically graded ones. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1703321/10014